# UTF8 and BibTeX problems

Tags: bibtex, errors

I laid last hands on my project. I added some sources. But than everything just blew up. Hopefully you can help me!

Here are the error(s):

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:̈ not set up for use with LaTeX.
See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.6 ...das den Menschen die gestohlene Zeit zurü
ckbrachte : ein
Your command was ignored.
Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,
or <return> to continue without it.
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:̈ not set up for use with LaTeX.
See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.7 Mä
rchen-Roman}.
Your command was ignored.
Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,
or <return> to continue without it.
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:̈ not set up for use with LaTeX.
See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.8 \newblock Heyne, Mü
nchen, 1996.
Your command was ignored.
Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,
or <return> to continue without it.
)
AED: lastpage setting LastPage
[1
]
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 85.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 85.
(./videnskabsteori_1.aux)
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 85.
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 85.
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `videnskabsteori_1.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck) Checksum: F82BC2727126FD8867B6303A26AE863C;41.
)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
29542 strings out of 493486
594360 string characters out of 3143550
636803 words of memory out of 3000000
32345 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
13316 words of font info for 42 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
957 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
56i,11n,55p,841b,795s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
Output written on videnskabsteori_1.dvi (1 page, 7872 bytes).
```

Here is my bibtex source

```
@Book{kragh,
 author = {Kragh, Helge},
 title = {Naturerkendelse og videnskabsteori: de uorganiske videnskabers filosofi og historie},
 publisher = {Aarhus Universitetsforlag},
 year = {2004},
 address = {Aarhus},
 isbn = {9788779341432},
 }

@Book{momo,
 author = {Ende, Michael},
 title = {Momo oder Die seltsame Geschichte von den Zeit-Dieben und von dem Kind, das den Menschen die gestohlene Zeit zurückbrachte : ein Märchen-Roman},
 publisher = {Heyne},
 year = {1996},
 address = {München},
 isbn = {978-3-453-11813-3}
 }

@Book{sander,
 author = {},
 title = {Regeringens handlingsplan Nye veje mellem forskning og erhverv - fra tanke til faktura},
 publisher = {Ministeriet for Videnskab, Teknologi og Udvikling},
 year = {2003},
 address = {City},
 isbn = {87-91258-72-3}
 }

@MISC{spiegel,
  AUTHOR       = "Ina Brzoska",
  TITLE        = "Pharma-Firmen an der Uni: Künftige Ärzte trainieren ihr Lobby-Immunsystem",
  YEAR         = "2010",
  MONTH        = "November",
  HOWPUBLISHED = "Website",
  NOTE         = "          \url{http://www.spiegel.de/unispiegel/studium/lobbyismus-medizinstudenten-wehren-sich-gegen-die-pharmaindustrie-a-868977.html}; besøgt den 13. april 2015."
}
```

And here is my source code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman, danish]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%Cite
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\makeatletter

\tikzset{%
  fancy quotes/.style={
    text width=\fq@width pt,
    align=justify,
    inner sep=1em,
    anchor=north west,
    minimum width=\linewidth,
  },
  fancy quotes width/.initial={.8\linewidth},
  fancy quotes marks/.style={
    scale=8,
    text=white,
    inner sep=0pt,
  },
  fancy quotes opening/.style={
    fancy quotes marks,
  },
  fancy quotes closing/.style={
    fancy quotes marks,
  },
  fancy quotes background/.style={
    show background rectangle,
    inner frame xsep=0pt,
    background rectangle/.style={
      fill=gray!25,
      rounded corners,
    },
  }
}

\newenvironment{fancyquotes}[1][]{%
\noindent
\tikzpicture[fancy quotes background]
\node[fancy quotes opening,anchor=north west] (fq@ul) at (0,0) {``};
\tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(fq@ul.east)
\pgfmathsetmacro{\fq@width}{\linewidth - 2*\pgf@x}
\node[fancy quotes,#1] (fq@txt) at (fq@ul.north west) \bgroup}
{\egroup;
\node[overlay,fancy quotes closing,anchor=east] at (fq@txt.south east) {''};
\endtikzpicture}

\makeatother

%MINT-pakker
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemfig, chemmacros}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\DeclareMathOperator\erf{erf}

%Hyperlinks
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\urlstyle{rm}

%Caption
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}

%Header/Footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\begin{document}



\section{Kilder}

\bibliography{kilder}
\bibliographystyle{plain}


\end{document}
```

Hopefully you can help me?

Kind regards and thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If you use BibTeX, don't use anything but "plain ASCII" characters in the bib file(s). Have you checked out the posting [How to write “ä” and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743/5001)

Comment: There are no `\cite` commands in your (non minimal) code, so I doubt that it really can produce the error.

Comment: I don't know: I just copied the code from his post, used `bibtex` in a first time and had the same error message, then changed as indicated and it worked fine after I removed the auxiliary files created by bibtex.

Comment: It seems (from the mentioned error messages) that relevant topics is http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94418

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer.)

If I include the instructions `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in the preamble, I am unable to reproduce the errors you report having encountered, using the bib entries you posted. You may want to check your editor's input encoding settings, just in case these settings involve an encoding that's not UTF8.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}  % just for this example
\begin{filecontents}{kilder.bib}
@Book{kragh,
 author = {Kragh, Helge},
 title = {Naturerkendelse og videnskabsteori: de uorganiske videnskabers filosofi og historie},
 publisher = {Aarhus Universitetsforlag},
 year = {2004},
 address = {Aarhus},
 isbn = {9788779341432},
}

@Book{momo,
 author = {Ende, Michael},
 title = {Momo oder Die seltsame Geschichte von den Zeit-Dieben und von dem Kind, das den Menschen die gestohlene Zeit zurückbrachte: Ein Märchen-Roman},
 publisher = {Heyne},
 year = {1996},
 address = {München},
 isbn = {978-3-453-11813-3}
}

@Book{sander,
 author = {Sander},
 title = {Regeringens handlingsplan Nye veje mellem forskning og erhverv - fra tanke til faktura},
 publisher = {Ministeriet for Videnskab, Teknologi og Udvikling},
 year = {2003},
 address = {City},
 isbn = {87-91258-72-3}
}

@MISC{spiegel,
  AUTHOR       = "Ina Brzoska",
  TITLE        = "{Pharma-Firmen an der Uni: Künftige Ärzte trainieren ihr Lobby-Immunsystem}",
  YEAR         = "2010",
  MONTH        = "November",
  HOWPUBLISHED = "Website",
  NOTE         = "          \url{http://www.spiegel.de/unispiegel/studium/lobbyismus-medizinstudenten-wehren-sich-gegen-die-pharmaindustrie-a-868977.html}; besøgt den 13. april 2015."
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman, danish]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\hyphenation{web-site} % default: web-si-te (arggh!)

%%%Cite
%%\usepackage{tikz}
%%\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
%%\makeatletter
%%
%%\tikzset{%
%%  fancy quotes/.style={
%%    text width=\fq@width pt,
%%    align=justify,
%%    inner sep=1em,
%%    anchor=north west,
%%    minimum width=\linewidth,
%%  },
%%  fancy quotes width/.initial={.8\linewidth},
%%  fancy quotes marks/.style={
%%    scale=8,
%%    text=white,
%%    inner sep=0pt,
%%  },
%%  fancy quotes opening/.style={
%%    fancy quotes marks,
%%  },
%%  fancy quotes closing/.style={
%%    fancy quotes marks,
%%  },
%%  fancy quotes background/.style={
%%    show background rectangle,
%%    inner frame xsep=0pt,
%%    background rectangle/.style={
%%      fill=gray!25,
%%      rounded corners,
%%    },
%%  }
%%}
%%
%%\newenvironment{fancyquotes}[1][]{%
%%\noindent
%%\tikzpicture[fancy quotes background]
%%\node[fancy quotes opening,anchor=north west] (fq@ul) at (0,0) {``};
%%\tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(fq@ul.east)
%%\pgfmathsetmacro{\fq@width}{\linewidth - 2*\pgf@x}
%%\node[fancy quotes,#1] (fq@txt) at (fq@ul.north west) \bgroup}
%%{\egroup;
%%\node[overlay,fancy quotes closing,anchor=east] at (fq@txt.south east) {''};
%%\endtikzpicture}
%%
%%\makeatother

%%%MINT-pakker
%%\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
%%\usepackage{graphicx}
%%\usepackage{chemfig, chemmacros}
%%\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
%%\usepackage{multicol}
%%\DeclareMathOperator\erf{erf}

%Hyperlinks
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\urlstyle{rm}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

%%%Caption
%%\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}

%Header/Footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

%%\usepackage{lastpage}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{kilder}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `biblatex` +`biber` (which understands `utf8`),it compiles fine.

Just add these lines to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{kilder.bib}
```

and replace at the end of the document:

```
\bibliography{kilder}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

with:

```
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
```

[image]

Comment: I doubt that it will work fine for Basilius, as the error message indicates a problem with the encoding of the umlauts in the .bib-file.

Comment: You are right: biber corrects the utf8 by converting the u+combining accent to the correct glyph.